# Jquery (JSON) - How to read the Twitter trendwords?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

i have a problem with the Twitter API.
I just don't see how to get the first trend word. My problem is the date at the begining.

Hope someone can help me.

**js code**

```
  $.ajax({url:'http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/current.json?callback=?',dataType:'json', success:function(data)
  {
    $.each(data.trends, function(i)
    {
         console.log(''+data.trends+'');    

        // alert(data.trends.XXXXXXX.[0].name);           
    });      
  } });
```

**example**
http://jsfiddle.net/ay6j8/

Thank in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do another [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) in your each:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/current.jsoncallback=?',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( data ) {
            $.each(data.trends, function( date, trends ) {
                console.log(date);
                $.each(trends, function( i, trend ) {
                    console.log(trend);
                });
            });   
        }
    });
});
```